# Can this 4-bar hinged window be somehow adjusted?

Tags: windows, hinges

I have a window mounted on two Truth [34/35 Series 4-Bar Hinges](https://truth.com/products/Commercial-Window-Hardware/Hinges/34-35-Series-4-Bar-Hinges), as well as a [23 series single-arm](https://truth.com/products/Commercial-Window-Hardware/Operators/23-Series-Operators) operator. The operator bar is sitting too low relative to the hinge, resulting in the window being stuck close as the operator bar can't move past the hinge mechanism. Numerous [videos online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rwozr0yTAUo) show how to adjust 2-bar hinge mechanisms which have an adjustable screw but it seems like the 4-bar hinge doesn't have one, as far as I can tell from the manual.

Is there any way to adjust this hinge to move the window a tiny bit higher? Note that there is a small yellow piece with an adjustment screw - it only affects friction and doesn't actually move the window by a significant margin.

[image]

Comment: Move the complete hinge up.

Comment: @SolarMike sorry could you expand on that?

Comment: Shim underneath it… assuming it's mounted horizontally like the picture. Otherwise, there's room for adjustment  in the fixings, if it's mounted vertically. The fixing points are slotted not round. I don't know how this may marry to your 'operator bar' - I've never seen anything like it.